# Docker Apache 2 mounting volume - prevent files from /etc/httpd directory from deletion

Tags: docker, apache

I am trying to mount my custom conf files to /etc/httpd however, when I build docker compose, it will result to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` No such file or Directory

Apache docker-compose:

```
  apache:
    container_name: apache
    image: cytopia/apache-2.2
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./apache:/etc/httpd
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    networks:
      - project
```

apache directory :

```
- conf
- conf.d
- conf.v (virtual host)
```

I just want to overwrite the data inside /etc/httpd without deleting the other files/directories inside. If this is possible or not, please advice what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try first and [bind-mount those files individually](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-mount-single-file-in-volume#1-long-syntax), rather than the folder (which does override everything)

```yaml
 apache:
    container_name: apache
    image: cytopia/apache-2.2
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./apache/conf/aFile:/etc/httpd/conf/aFile:ro
      - ./apache/conf.d/aFile:/etc/httpd/conf.d/aFile:ro
      - ...
```

Comment: I would like to check if I understood, the volumes will overwrite everything? I will try these later. for now I am trying a different approach where I create a user that can do root privileges' commands inside container(cp)

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth If you [bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container). It creates a new layer to reflect the source directory mounted. That layer obscure what was present before mount.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I manually added the files one by one instead